# Setting ViewControllers of UITabBarController on iPhoneX misplaces the labels

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, iphone-x

We use storyboards for setting up our UITabBarController but filter the related ViewControllers using their tags within the `loadView()` of the UITabBarController:

```
if let filteredVCs = self.viewControllers?.filter({$0.tabBarItem.tag != hiddenTag }) {
    self.setViewControllers(filteredVCs, animated: false)
}
```

This was always working fine until the iPhone X. There it results in misplaced labels:

[image]

Without this code it is working fine:

[image]

We already tried `setNeedLayout()` on the UITabBar to relayout it after changing the viewControllers but it didn't work.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Comment: The code runs in the loadView() of a subclass of UITabBarController. The settings for which ViewController should appear are actually fetched before the UITabBarController is created and are not really important. Removed that section to reduce confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. While trying to reduce the necessary code to a minimal reproducible version I found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I confused some stuff and the code was not called in the `loadView()` which caused the issue. The code was running while the the UITabBar was not displayed but hidden behind modalview, which caused the issue. I now call the code in `loadView()` an it is working as expected.